# Open Interactive Animation format for Research

Tags: simulation, animation

The format should be

- open
- can make interactive animations with mouse
- easily integrable to other animations of the same format
- preferably converters from SWF (not necessary)

I cannot use SWF in the long-run because it is not open.
I run all the time into problems when I have to combine a few animations and make a new one.
I need to see the source code of the format and its tools to understand it.

To control system complexity and bind things together

- make

I think I partially go into the area of Mathematical simulation tools

- Matlab (I have problems in large scaling so no)
- SageMath (potential most)
- R (have to clarify still to myself where to use this exactly)

My current needs seem to be tools which I can port in terminal

- inkscape
- SWF (only for existing SWF documents; so probably best idea is to separate this from the main stream; so we can use LaTeX)
- R (this will be useful in controlling and binding different systems together)

**What is a good open interactive animation format for research?**

Comment: I would suggest you look into HTML5, as this is generally touted as the replacement for Flash (not just for video)

Answer (score 1):

### LaTeX

You can use LaTeX to create increadible animations. Some simple animations and explanations how to do so are [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152358/5645).

The idea is to create a PDF with multiple pages and every page is one frame of the animation. Then you can use standard tools to generate a gif animation (or whatever you want) from those single images.

### HTML5

It might be much easier to use a HTML5 `canvas` and JavaScript to generate animations. A good start is here: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/

Comment: Yes, I agree with these recommendations. Latex is not stable, unless we can figure out what we can do with SWF animations which I must use. Is it possible to embed my current latex documents which have SWF animations directly to HTML5? I found a related discussion about this here http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52928/a-html5-framework-for-drawing-images-with-latex-formula-support

Comment: More about Latex here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152358/animations-in-latex but it does not handle the stability problems which Latex has with SWF.

Comment: What do you mean with stability problems of LaTeX? I don't know any program that is more stable than TeX... Do you mean stability in the sense of unexpected program crash? If you must use SWF animations, you should have put that as a requirement in your question.

Comment: The thing is that I do not want restrict the freedom of this discussion because there may be better solutions that I do not know. SWF is just a bottleneck which I have, but which I may be able go around somehow. I use LaTeX at the moment mostly and just happy seeing your Makefile in typing Latex in your other answer. Have you used R in your makefiles to create visualisations?